# Simple way to communicate v-model changes between components in Vue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify to create a couple of components in a dashboard ([example code](https://codepen.io/blindpupil/pen/yKPpbm?editors=1010)). 
As you can see, I have a toolbar component:

```
Vue.component('toolbar', {                                     
  template: '
    <v-toolbar>
      <v-toolbar-side-icon @click="$emit('toggle')"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Application</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-toolbar>' 
});
```

I want to be able to click this toolbar to close the drawer component, so I emit an event for it: `@click="$emit('toggle')"`

Then, the drawer component listens with `@toggle` for that event to swap the boolean value of the `v-model=drawer`:

```
Vue.component('drawer', {                
  template: '
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" @toggle="drawer=!drawer" app>
    ...
    </v-navigation-drawer>',
  data() {   
    return { drawer: true } 
  }   
});
```

However, clicking on toggle doesn't change value of the `v-model`. In order for the Vuetify component to work I need to be able to change the v-model value, I don't think I can make it work with computed properties, so I guess this rules out using Vuex.

What would be the simplest way to handle the communication between these components?

Comment: Note that if you don't use components and instead place everything in a single Vue instance, it works correctly as you can see [here](https://codepen.io/johnjleider/pen/qxQWda?editors=1010): https://codepen.io/johnjleider/pen/qxQWda?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of changes that needs to be done:

- add the property `drawer: true` on the root instance where the `drawer` component is rendered as pass it as props to the `drawer` component

  ```
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
           drawer: true
        }
        
      })
  ```

  **template**

  ```
  <drawer :drawer="drawer"></drawer> // pass drawer as props
  ```
- Receive the `drawer` prop in the **drawer** component and set it to the `v-model` of `<v-navigation-drawer>`

  ```
  Vue.component('drawer', {
    template: `
      <v-navigation-drawer clipped fixed app v-model="drawer">
        ...
      </v-navigation-drawer>`,

    props: {
      drawer: Boolean,
      source: String
    }
  });
  ```
- you are emitting an event from the `toolbar` component. So you should add the event listener on the `toolbar` component , not the `drawer` component.

  ```
  <toolbar @toggle="drawer = !drawer"></toolbar>
  ```

Here is the updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aYVYzQ?editors=1010#anon-login

Comment: I get a warning when the value changes because of resizing:
"Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value."

Comment: @CesarMartinezDominguez the codepen i provided does not log any errors except for a warning saying `source` is not defined on the root instance which you are using in `<v-tooltip>`

Comment: try resizing the window. That's when the alert appears.

Comment: @CesarMartinezDominguez add `disable-resize-watcher` on `v-navigation-drawer` component to disable automatic opening and closing of drawer on window resize. If you still want drawer to be hidden on smaller devices replace `fixed` with `temporary` prop. See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aYVYzQ?editors=1010#anon-login

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, the codepen you provided does give the error message previously reported. `Prop` is not a good option for this.